# Optimizar código que recorre filas

Tags: excel, vba, bucles

Tengo un código que recorre filas y evalúa valores en una hoja para luego ir sumando 1 al orden si se cumple la condición. El problema es que la hoja ronda las 18.000 filas y la macro está ejecutándose tres o cuatro minutos... que es excesivo.

El resultado debería ser así:

```
CODIGO|MOTIVO|FAMILIA|ORDEN
1000  |9007  |1000   |1
350008|      |1000   |2
1001  |9007  |1001   |1
35093 |      |1001   |2
12534 |      |1001   |3
1002  |9007  |1122   |1
35154 |      |1122   |2
```

Lo que necesito rellenar es la columna orden, que comienza desde 1 cada vez que cambio de familia (marcado también por el campo motivo 9007).

Este es el código que tengo hecho y que tanto me tarda:

```
For i = 2 To uf

    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value = 9007 Then

        j = 1
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value = j

    Else
        j = Sheet1.Cells(i - 1, 5).Value
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value = j + 1

    End If

Next
```

uf es la última fila de la hoja.

A ver si alguien me da una idea de cómo hacer más rápido.

Gracias.

Comment: No se si esto te puede servir de ayuda, pero ahí hay un ejemplo en el que recorre *1 millón de filas* en 0.249 segundos. Hecha un vistazo: https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/2110417

Comment: He visto tu enlace y he probado a recorrerlo como rango, pero aún así sigue tardando bastante, ya que sigo necesitando un If... para evaluar el contenido. Probaré con un array a ver si me aclaro.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He realizado pruebas con tu código y no tarda tanto, apenas unos 10 segundos con 30 mil registros.

Quizá el problema esta en que tu libro tiene muchas formulas, podrías retrasar el calculo de la hoja con `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` , eso se pone al inicio de la macro, al final se pone `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

En la mayoría de los casos es mas rápido recorrer datos en memoria, es decir, convertir un rango en una matriz de datos y recorrer esa matriz.

Este ejemplo puede ayudar.

```
Sub recorre()
    Dim uf, j As Long
    Dim data() As Variant

    uf = Hoja1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    data = Hoja1.Range("A2:C" & uf).Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(data)

        If data(i, 2) = 9007 Then

            j = 1
            Hoja1.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = j

        Else
            j = Hoja1.Cells(i, 4).Value
            Hoja1.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = j + 1

        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Pues no se me había ocurrido el parar el cálculo de fórmulas. Es posible que sea cómo dices ya que en el fichero de prueba que estoy montando si que tengo muchas fórmulas y probablemente sea eso lo que se me esté escapando.

Pruebo y te comento. 

Gracias.

Comment: @dogwall `With Application` `.ScreenUpdating = False` `.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` `.EnableEvents = False` `End With`. Pon cada trozo en una fila, justo antes de empezar la macro y luego al final cambiando los valores de `False` por `True`y el calculation a automático. De todas formas, como dice Nolberto, cuando trates muchos datos hazlos en un array, y luego vuelve a volcar el array en la hoja (falta esa parte en este código).

Comment: Probado el código de @Nolberto y funcionando. Mucho más rápido recorrer la matriz y actualizar las filas al mismo tiempo que recorrer las filas.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pues utilizando fórmulas se hace en apenas un segundo sin complicarse mucho más la vida:

```
With Sheet1.Range("E2:E" & uf)

    .FormulaLocal = "=SI(C2=9007;1;E1+1)"
    .FormulaLocal = .Value

End With
```

Así que con esto me vale.

Comment: `.Value = .Value` sería la correcto para convertir las fórmulas en valores.

Comment: En qué se diferencia? El resultado, aparentemente, es el mismo ¿no?

Comment: Por cierto, el uso de la formula convertida a valor también es buena opción, siempre y cuando se detenga el calculo automático al inicio y se reactive al final, pero en términos generales es mejor el manejo del array porque te da mas versatilidad cuando se requiere hacer mas de una cosa en cada iteración, en este caso el uso de la formula aplica igual o mejor porque es mas corto el código, no es tan practico si por cada ciclo ( fila ) se tuvieran que hacer mas cosas.